# Fatal error RC1212

Tags: c++, debugging, visual-studio-2012, release

I try to build one project (huge but not finished program, not mine but I guess I should be one of the guys who will try finish it).

Actually when I build it in Debug mode, everything seems like okay, but when I switch into Release mode an error appears:

> fatal error RC1212: invalid option - /z argument missing  substitute font name

I trying to change options into `Project properties->C++->General->Debug Information Format` but it doesn't help.

Never saw such error before. Does anyone know how to fix it?

Thank you!

Comment: /z is an undocumented command line option for rc.exe.  Look at Project + Properties, Resources, Command Line and remove anything that resembles /z.